# What kind of breakers might work in this panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, gfci

I want to install a double pole 30 amp GFCI breaker in this panel, but I can't figure out what kind of breakers I need.

Is there a way to tell from the pictures I have attached?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The best solution is to replace the panel. Sylvania breaker panels are on the bad list. Check with your insurance company, I have been told some insurance companies will not cover a fire if caused by a Sylvania panel. Some Sylviana breakers can be replaced by the Cutler-Hammer BR series, it is a direct replacement for some panels. Google sylvania breaker replacement you should find a lot of information.

Comment: @Gil -- this is a Sylvania-Challenger panel, and thus takes Eaton BR breakers -- about the only potential problem is that some Challenger panels used Zinsco-style breakers for their mains (type QFBs) and it's not clear how to replace them with a safer type of breaker

Comment: @Gil -- further more, the OP's panel is cross-labeled for type BR, settling any doubts